# Windows 7 screen size is too large and colors are off

Tags: windows-7, windows

I was having a lot of trouble with Windows 7. After I logged on, I couldn't do anything, not even open the start menu. And I don't understand why. My CPU and Memory shows in the top right corner, and their statuses were fine. I pulled the plug and tried to start fresh, but the same thing went on.

Eventually, I decided to install a fresh installation of Windows 7, but I had to do it in Safe Mode. Now that the installation is done, the colors of my desktop are off and the screen size is too large. Also, I have a screen tablet connected to my laptop. The colors are accurate on the laptop but not the tablet. And In the Control Panel, I am being told that the screen size is at it's smallest value, but that can't be right. Can someone please help me to fix the size and colors?

And for future reference, could someone also please help me to understand why my computer could've been so slow before if CPU and RAM were fine? I am constantly installing new software, but CPU, RAM, and Disk Space has plenty of room. However, I wonder if it has anything to do with monitoring. There is a location in my external hard drive where I store files, but it was in my Videos folder. I never put it there, nor could I remove them from that location. I had Kaspersky installed, so I would think it would detect if there were any ransomware on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just write that you plugged of computer's power cable? It can damage computer's hardware.

The small screen resolution and bad colours may indicate that proper graphics driver is not installed. Try updating the video driver or reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've just done a fresh install, you'll need to install the correct drivers for your video card.

Once that is done and you have restarted, adjusting the resolution slider in display properties will get you the "screen size" you want.  If items are appearing too large in Windows 7, you'll want to increase the resolution so that they scale down.

If your colors still seem incorrect, make sure that you have the proper refresh rate frequency, and that the VGA cable is plugged in fully and in good condition.

Without knowing the model of your tablet, it's possible that Windows is cloning the display rather than extending it, causing your monitor to share the same resolution as your tablet.

How does one install Windows in safe mode?  Installing Windows bypasses the existing version of Windows, so you would not boot, safe mode or otherwise, into Windows at all.  Excluding in place upgrades, or just starting the installation process (restarting) is that what you did?

Computers seem slow when programs access resources behind the scenes, e.g. when Kapersky does a hard disk scan it will react much slower to user requests.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the delayed response. I was busy with Easter.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Where can the drivers be downloaded?

I didn't think installing Windows in Safe Mode would work but it did. However, it was "Safe Mode and Network," not just Safe Mode.

And just so I don't keep making the same mistake because I run into computer problems very frequently, is there a downside of constantly installing new software even if the computer specs are doable?

Comment: Hi Brian, what you describe sounds like you simply entered safe mode, then ran the windows installer, which restarted and installed windows regularly (as you obviously cannot install windows into windows without a virtual machine :D) Drivers can be obtained via windows update, or from the vendor for your card:  1 https://downloadcenter.intel.com 2 http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx 3 http://support.amd.com/en-us/download
If you are uncertain, install CPU-Z to see what graphics chip you have.
The downside of more programs is the time it takes to load, and resources they require while on.